# Share Point authentication in iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, sharepoint

I have searched for **"Share Point authentication in iOS"** and I have gone through the results but I am unable to properly understand about
**What is Share Point Authentication?**
**What make it different from other authentication methods like oAuth?** 
And 
**How to implement Share Point Authentication in iOS?**
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search and **concern to my seniors** I found two links using ether way I found my solution. The links are:
**1) Using UIWebView**
Here I only need to pass an URL to `UIWebView`. If the URL is openable then `Office 365` login view will open on your `UIWebView`, where you can enter your login credentials. You can find full description with related code at [here.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571996/Development-of-iPhone-client-application-for-Share)
An other solution is
**2) Creating your own UI for login**
Here you have to design your own UI and full manual code to authenticate. You can find all the required help related to code, I can say full code from [here.](http://omicron-llama.co.uk/2012/12/13/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-in-ios/).
**If anyone find my question and/or answer useful then please up vote both or ether of the post. Thank you in advance.**